# jQuery: Enabling a text field based on selecting a certain drop down value

Tags: jquery

I think I am very close to solving this, but I am going wrong somewhere.

If from the dropdown 'Mercedes' is selected, then the text input should be enabled (note with the actual system there are no class or id names so I have to go by the form name).

I also need it to check on initial page load if this value is set to Mercedes, in that case the input should not be showing either.

This is what I have so far ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fakeguybrushthreepwood/bZvAE/)):

HTML:

**Your Car:**

```
<select name="car">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<br>
What do you like about your Mercedes?
<input type="text" name="likemercedes">
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("input[type='text'][name='likemercedes']").prop('disabled', true);

if($("input[type='text'][name='car']").val() == "mercedes") 
{
    $("input[type='text'][name='likemercedes']").removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something simple:

```
$("select[name=car]").change(function() {
    if (this.value == "mercedes")
        $("input[name=likemercedes]").prop("disabled", false);
    else
        $("input[name=likemercedes]").prop("disabled", true);
}).change();
```

The chaining `.change()` at the end will invoke the method on page-load.

Answer (score 1):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/28uNE/)

```
$("select[name=car]").on("change", function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "mercedes") {
        $("input[type='text'][name='likemercedes']").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
}).trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Car:

```
<select abc="facility" >
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<br>What do you like about your Mercedes?
<input name="test" type="text" id="disabled_input"/>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#disabled_input').attr('disabled','disabled');
    $('select[abc="facility"]').on('change',function(){
    var  others = $(this).val();
        if(others == "mercedes"){           
            $('#disabled_input').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        else{
            $('#disabled_input').attr('disabled','disabled');
        }  

    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Noman_009/1jmrbr51/2/)